# setting the rate of fire of bullets in Actionscript 3 game

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to limit the rate of fire of my bullets in an Actionscript 3 game I have made.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Below is my code.

```
//shooting bullet
function shoot(Evt:MouseEvent)
{
    var sound2 = new bullet_shoot();
    sound2.play();
    if (bulletCounter < 5)
    {
        bulletCounter++;
    }
    else
    {
        bulletCounter = 0;
    }
    shootmc(bulletArray[bulletCounter]);
}

function shootmc(mc:MovieClip)
{
    mc.visible = true;
    mc.x = spaceman_mc.x;
    mc.y = spaceman_mc.y;
    mc.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `function shoot()`, set a delay/countdown variable which prevents shooting if larger than `0`. For example:

```
function shoot(Evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (shootDelay == 0) {

        // set shoot delay
        shootDelay = 10;

        // shoot logic
        var sound2 = new bullet_shoot();
        if (bulletCounter < 5) bulletCounter++;
        else bulletCounter = 0;
        shootmc(bulletArray[bulletCounter]);
    }
}
```

Now, you must still ensure that `shootDelay` is decreased once per frame/update if it is larger than `0`, otherwise you would never be able to fire again. You can either call an `update()` method each frame, or subscribe to the `ENTER_FRAME` event and do your update in the corresponding event listener. A simple `update()` method would look like this:

```
public function update():void {
    if (shootDelay > 0) shootDelay --;
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: more usefull will be setInterval than ENTER_FRAME , because event depends on framerate